# How to make a catch all route to handle '404 page not found' queries for ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, http-status-code-404

Is it possible to create a final route that catches all .. and bounces the user to a 404 view in ASP.NET MVC?

NOTE: I don't want to set this up in my IIS settings.

Comment: See my answer to "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/619895/how-can-i-properly-handle-404-in-asp-net-mvc/23830145#23830145".

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Found the answer myself.

[Richard Dingwall](http://richarddingwall.name/2008/08/17/strategies-for-resource-based-404-errors-in-aspnet-mvc/) has an excellent post going through various strategies. I particularly like the FilterAttribute solution. I'm not a fan of throwing exceptions around willy nilly, so i'll see if i can improve on that :)

For the global.asax, just add this code as your last route to register:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "404-PageNotFound",
    "{*url}",
    new { controller = "StaticContent", action = "PageNotFound" }
    );
```

Comment: I've tried this, but it doesn't work. I have put the route under my default route, but i still get 404 errors.

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly I have to assuming I am very new to MVC.

Comment: 2 things. a) add that last route to your route list. b) create a controller (in my example, i called it StaticContentController) with an Action method (in my example, i added a method called PageNotFound(..)) add logic this method to display the 404 page not found, View.

Comment: If you still have the default route (I.E. {controller}/{action}/{id}) in RegisterRoutes() it will trap all URLs that match the format of a normal MVC request.

In other words the catch-all route can only intercept a bad URL if it doesn't fit the normal format (**blah/blah/blah/blah**). 

In the case of a non-existent controller the exception must be handled through conventional ASP.NET handling.

Theres a good description of handling at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/619895/how-can-i-properly-handle-404s-in-asp-net-mvc/620559#620559

Comment: Indeed the 'catch all' is maybe not the best approach. Feedback on this answer pls: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/619895/how-can-i-properly-handle-404s-in-asp-net-mvc/2577095#2577095

Comment: @RonnBlack is right. I overcome this by just explicitly create a route for each controller. BUT the magic `{*url}` still not overcome this issue. What if the mapped URL into route is available but the controller/action itself did not found. If I browse to /Home/About123 ugly asp.net error page still come out because the route not reach to the `{*url}` but handled in my home route.

Comment: Make sure that your routes are mapped in the correct order.

Comment: @Pure.Krome: is it not in your Routeconfig you must add the code.

Answer (score 20):

This question came first, but the easier answer came in a later question:

[Routing for custom ASP.NET MVC 404 Error page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553922/custom-asp-net-mvc-404-error-page)

> I got my error handling to work by creating an ErrorController that
>   returns the views in this article. I also had to add the "Catch All"
>   to the route in global.asax.
>
> I cannot see how it will get to any of these error pages if it is not
>   in the Web.config..? My Web.config had to specify:
>
> ```
> customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error/Unknown"
> ```
>
> and then I also added:
>
> ```
> error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/NotFound"
> ```
>
> Hope this helps.

I love this way now because it is so simple:

```
 <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error/" redirectMode="ResponseRedirect">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/PageNotFound/" />
 </customErrors>
```

Comment: That's what I have now, but I'm trying to replace it with a better solution which will not first send a 302 response to the client but a 404 directly. Change the redirectMode to ResponseRewrite and you'll find it does not work any more... :-(

Comment: @LouisSomers Since this answer, I have found the better way is the one described in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171035/asp-net-mvc-custom-error-handling-application-error-global-asax I prefer not to redirect the user to a different URL because it is less user-friendly (even I find it annoying while developing). Cheers.

Comment: I'm getting the error `Config Error: The configuration section 'customErrors' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration`.

Answer (score 7):

Also you can handle NOT FOUND error in Global.asax.cs as below

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception lastErrorInfo = Server.GetLastError();
    Exception errorInfo = null;

    bool isNotFound = false;
    if (lastErrorInfo != null)
    {
        errorInfo = lastErrorInfo.GetBaseException();
        var error = errorInfo as HttpException;
        if (error != null)
            isNotFound = error.GetHttpCode() == (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
    }
    if (isNotFound)
    {
        Server.ClearError();
        Response.Redirect("~/Error/NotFound");// Do what you need to render in view
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Add this lines under your project root web.config File.

```
 <system.webServer>
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
  <remove statusCode="404" />
  <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Test/PageNotFound" />
  <remove statusCode="500" />
  <error statusCode="500" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Test/PageNotFound" />
</httpErrors>
<modules>
  <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
</modules>
```

Comment: Thank you this is what I needed. In case anyone falls into the same issue as me existingResponse="Replace" fixed it. I had Auto set in there before which is the suggested option in most posts. I guess auto in my case scenario was not able to determine to use replace.

Answer (score 3):

This might be a problem when you use

```
throw new HttpException(404);
```

When you want to catch that, I don't know any other way then editing your web config.

Comment: ActionFilters : use them to catch the HttpException.

Comment: What if the exception is not thrown by a controller action? I throw a 404 in my controller factory.

Comment: Not sure then - i'm not playing around with controller factories. soz.

Comment: Controllerfactory is not the only place where it can happen. I map a catch all route to an actionmethod that just throws the exception. The exception is handled by the web.config

Comment: Throw any `Exception` you want. Let all your controller derived from a `BaseController`. In this `BaseController` you override `OnException` and set the filterContext.Result either redirect or view result.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to creating a catch-all route is to add an `Application_EndRequest` method to your `MvcApplication` per [Marco's Better-Than-Unicorns MVC 404 Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9026907/145173).

Answer (score 1):

Inside `RouterConfig.cs` add the follwing piece of code:

```
  routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Error",
           url: "{id}",
           defaults: new
           {
               controller = "Error",
               action = "PageNotFound"

           });
```

Answer (score 0):

If the route cannot be resolved, then MVC framework will through 404 error.. 
Best approach is to use Exception Filters ... Create a custom exceptionfilter and make like this..

```
public class RouteNotFoundAttribute : FilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter {
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext) {
        filterContext.Result  = new RedirectResult("~/Content/RouteNotFound.html");
   }
}
```