# CustomErrors on doesn't work on production

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling

I hav asp.net mvc 3 application.

When user pass id of non existing object I return 404 view in this way:

```
Response.StatusCode = 404;
return View("404");
```

Locally all works fine and I have my custom error page. But on production, I have standart asp.net 404 page. I try to set customErrors either to "on" or "off" - results is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution here: [Routing for custom ASP.NET MVC 404 Error page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553922/custom-asp-net-mvc-404-error-page)

Set another magic setting in web config under system.webServer section:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<system.webServer>
    ...
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL">
        <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" 
            path="/errors/404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
```

Also, there is a new way you can return 404 from an action method:

```
// Response.StatusCode = 404;
// return View("404");
return HttpNotFound();
```