# Custom Error Page does not show even though I set CustomError="On"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling, web-config, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using Visual Studio 2012 with the MVC 4 Framework and would like to see the friendly error page of the shared folder, if an exception is unhandled. (I know, as a develepor I need to see the error details but I just wanted to test this setting)
So far I know that adding the following code in the system.web section of web.config should do the trick

```
<customErrors mode="On" />
```

Unfortunately instead of my friendly error page I get this:

> ### Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Runtime Error  Description: An application error occurred on the
>   server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent
>   the details of the application error from being viewed.
>
> Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be
>   viewable on the local server machine, please create a 
>   tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root
>   directory of the current web application. This  tag
>   should then have its "mode" attribute set to "RemoteOnly". To enable
>   the details to be viewable on remote machines, please set "mode" to
>   "Off".

```
 <!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

 <configuration>
     <system.web>
         <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"/>
     </system.web> </configuration>
```

> Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a
>   custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the
>   application's  configuration tag to point to a custom
>   error page URL.

```
 <!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

 <configuration>
     <system.web>
         <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
     </system.web> </configuration>
```

I would like to do it as described and not with a workaround like adding an action to HomeController, setting routes or something. 
A reference that this should work is the following: 
<s>http://pluralsight.com/training/players/PSODPlayer?author=scott-allen&name=mvc3-building-controllers&mode=live&clip=0&course=aspdotnet-mvc3-intro 

(On left select the chapter "Action Filters" and skip to minute 3:30)</s> 

**UPDATE (link changed):** 
http://pluralsight.com/training/Player?author=scott-allen&name=mvc4-building-m2-controllers&mode=live&clip=0&course=mvc4-building 
(On top click on the thin line that states "Controller in ASP.NET MVC 4", then click on "Action Filters" and skip to minute 5:00)


Does anybody have a clue why I cannot see the friendly error page with the setting mentioned above? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11):

Here is step by step guide to doing this,

To start with, first set the “customErrors’s” mode property to ‘on’. (This specifies that custom errors are enabled.)

**1. Code from Web.config**

```
<system.web>

    <customErrors mode="On"></customErrors>

</system.web>
```

Below is my controller code, I have specified the HandleError attribute on the controller class. Also to generate an error I am throwing an exception from the Index action.

**2. Code from HomeController.cs**

```
[HandleError]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
    throw new Exception("Error Occured !");
    ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

    return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
    return View();
    }
}
```

As you can see in the screenshot below, I have a Error.cshtml view defined inside the Shared folder of the Views folder.

**3. Solution Explorer**

[image]

Note that the Error.cshtml view (shown below) uses a model of ‘System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo’

**4. Code from Error.cshtml**

```
@model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Error";
}

<h2>
    Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request.
</h2>
```

On running the project, instead of getting the yellow death screen now I get the following output.

[image]

Taken from [this article](http://yassershaikh.com/how-to-use-handleerror-in-mvc-3-with-example/)

**Update :**

Try this out by creating a new project, this should and does work. I suspect that your `Error.cshtml` file may not have model as `@model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo` or you may be having multiple Error.cshtml pages in different view folders.

Comment: Unfortunately, for me it still did not work.
I've done as you told me.
Furthermore, the HandleErrorAttribute is registered by default in global.asax so I usually don't need to set that Attribute for the Homecontroller.

Comment: @L4_ If it is still not working, see the [answer about editing the right web.config](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15500222/3116322) - that's what was causing the issue in my case.

Comment: I'm glad I found this. I was going mad because 1) I was editing the wrong web.config, and 2) I didn't have the model as `System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo`. +1!

Answer (score 5):

I fixed mine.. It's actually the *_Layout* page cannot be rendered because my `_Layout.cshtml` was strongly typed to a base view model which `HandleErrorInfo` can't be casted into. And you can never see this page binding error because it only happens when `customError` is on... that's just great.

Comment: I am "do'hing!" so hard right now! Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 5):

One reason that could lead to what you are experiencing:

Something in your _layout is causing an exception to throw when the 'Error.cshtml' is rendering.

Do a test adding

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
```

in your 'Error.cshtml' file.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when I was updating the wrong `web.config` file.

There is a `web.config` in the `Views` folder and also under the project application site.

The solution would be to update `web.config` located under project.

Comment: Sorry for my late answer ;) but I already had updated the right web.config as you mentioned. Anyway the problem still persists.

Comment: I am on MVC3 and just added the below settings to web.config and custom page and it works for me.  
  
`<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml">  
`   <error redirect="~/Home/NotFound" statusCode="404" />  
'</customErrors>

Answer (score -1):

This does not work with Visual Studio Express Edition. It works if you are using Professional or Ultimate Edition of Visual Studio IDE.