# MVC CustomError not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to debug in VS express 2013 with my MVC4 application.

In a view, I've added a nonsense link, such as `<a href="blah.asf">link,</a>` but I don't see the intended View when I click on the link, I see the IIS page.

I did this by creating an ErrorController which is

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

My view remains as the default, I didn't update it.

And my webconfig is

```
  <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error">
  </customErrors>
```

The routes are the default!

The IIS message is

```
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
```

If I type in `http://localhost:53258/error/` then I see the page, suggesting that the mapping is fine.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure why you think that the only requirement to display an error is to create an `ErrorController` that is very much not the case.

Comment: Fair to assume that the ~/Error route is mapped?

Comment: @ErikPhilips, I don't, hence the update to the web.config and the view...

Comment: @NathanTaylor, I tested it (and updated post), the page renders when I go there by typing http://localhost:53258/error/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom Error Page does not show even though I set CustomError="On"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12823520/custom-error-page-does-not-show-even-though-i-set-customerror-on)

Comment: This is not a dupe. The dupe cited is for a 500 error - my page resolves if I go direct!

Answer (score 0):

Check for this in your web.config, and add it if you don't have it:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="PassThrough" />
```

Comment: I get an error of `the existingResponse attribute is not allowed`. I tried it, but it makes no difference

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your `customErrors` node to add this:

```
<error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error" />
```

Thus, your custom errors section would look like:

```
<customErrors mode="On">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error" />
</customErrors>
```