# ASP.NET MVC Error 500 When Pushed to Production Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, production-environment

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC 4 in C# project which works very well on my local development server. However, when I push it to my production server, a particular page gives a 500 internal server error. However, the error I get is no more helpful than "An error occurred while processing your request".

How can I force ASP.NET to display a more helpful error, even if it is the yellow screen of death?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom ASP.NET MVC 404 Error Page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553922/custom-asp-net-mvc-404-error-page)

Comment: Look at the Event Viewer and see if you can find anything in there...

Comment: Try to add a global error handler with logging capabilities

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there's a Yellow Screen of Death. You can force it to display the error by going to the `Web.Config` file and making sure that you have this line:

```
<system.web>
   <customErrors defaultRedirect="GenericError.htm"
    mode="Off"></customErrors>
</system.web>
```

**BUT** be very careful NOT to leave it like this after you figure out the issue. It is BIG a security risk to display full stack traces of errors on a Production box.