# ASP NET MVC full stack trace for exception in production

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exception

I have an ASP.NET MVC application and I log exceptions to email. It works fine from a local machine but when deployed to production, I don't get a full stack trace for the exception. It just reports `"System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object at MyApplication.Web.Controllers.AccessController.Index()"`.

How can I get full stack trace including line numbers? Thanks!

```
namespace MyApplication.Web.Controllers
{
  public class AccessController : Controller
  {

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
      try
      {
        //code
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        var exceptionString = ex.ToString();
        //Send email 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Deploy the PDB files along with the DLLs.

Comment: @BenRobinson Is it safe to deploy PDB files to production? Does those affect application performance?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC Error 500 When Pushed to Production Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23297449/asp-net-mvc-error-500-when-pushed-to-production-server)