# ASP.NET MVC not obeying httpErrors entry in web.config

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config

I'm trying to execute my custom error controller action when a user tries to visit a non-existing URL. I've added this:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="PassThrough">
      <remove statusCode="404"/>
      <error statusCode="404" path="error/404-not-found" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
</httpErrors>
```

I also have a controller for errors, and I confirm that `/error/404-not-found` is accessible (I see the correct error page). However, when I try to visit a non-existent URL, I'm still getting the regular "Server error in / Application" 404 error instead of my custom error page. I've also tried different existingResponse and responseMode values but no avail. How do I get my 404 errors redirect to my page?

Comment: Have you tried using `redirect`? `<error statusCode="404" redirect="~/error/404-not-found" />`. Have a look at to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7442327/1380428).

Comment: @AdilMammadov having used ASP.NET MVC for several years now, and I've just realized there are two different error handling mechanisms in web.config: httpErrors and customErrors. Terrible design decision at Microsoft's side. Anyway, using custom errors fixed the issue for me.

Comment: I am glad that it helped.You can also refer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2481102/1380428) for differences between *httpErrors* and *customErrors*. Be sure to read comments also. Thank you too.