# ASP.NET MVC Routing Help

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I have the following url(s):

```
http://localhost/About
http://localhost/Contact
http://localhost/Shop
http://localhost/Shop/ListProducts/{CategoryID}/{CategoryName}
http://localhost/Shop/Checkout
http://localhost/Customer
http://localhost/Customer/Edit
http://localhost/Customer/ChangePassword
http://localhost/Authentication/LogOn
http://localhost/Authentication/LogOff
```

And the following maps:

```
routes.MapRoute("Authentication", "Authentication/{action}", New With {.controller = "Authentication", .action = "Index"})
routes.MapRoute("Customer", "Customer/{action}", New With {.controller = "Customer", .action = "Index"})
routes.MapRoute("Shop", "Shop/{action}/{CategoryID}/{CategoryName}", New With {.controller = "Shop", .action = "Index", .CategoryID = UrlParameter.Optional, .CategoryName = UrlParameter.Optional})
routes.MapRoute("Main", "{action}", New With {.controller = "Main", .action = "Index"})
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", New With {.controller = "Main", .action = "Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional})
```

While this seems to work, I need a way to handle unknown routes/urls with a 404.

I have looked at a few samples here, and cant' seem to make them work.

Also, do these routes look right? Am I on the right track?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track - see this posting to handle ALL 404s.

[How can i make a catch all route to handle '404 page not found' queries for ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310580/how-can-i-make-a-catch-all-route-to-handle-404-page-not-found-queries-for-asp-n)

specifically this part

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "404-PageNotFound",
    "{*url}",
    new { controller = "StaticContent", action = "PageNotFound" }
    );
```