# Asp.net MVC4 mandatory route parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a RouteConfig like this

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"}
        );
    }
}
```

But when i am trying use "http://example.com/controllername/action/166699406". It is getting the error below. What I am trying to achieve is, I want to make the id parameter mandatory. If they dont have an id parameter in the url, it should not hit a route and should show 404. I know we can achieve this by null checking the parameter in the controller. Is there any way manage that in route config itself.

> No route in the route table matches the supplied values.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: No route in the route table matches the supplied values.

Answer (score 0):

You should handle this in web.confing not in routing.

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/error/default">
  <error statusCode="403" redirect="/error/restricted"/>
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="/Default/DefaultRoute"/>
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="/error/problem"/>
</customErrors>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to add a constraint to the route

```
constraints: new { id = @"([0-9]+)" }
```

this will mean the route will only match when id is a number, it is mandatory.

in full:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"},
            constraints: new { id = @"([0-9]+)" }
        );
```

Note that the route you gave in the question should match the rule you have currently so I'd double check your controller, action and spelling in case there is simply a typo there somewhere.

Comment: I tried this but getting the same error, when i am trying to access http://example.com/controllername/action/166699406

Comment: I'm guessing there is something wrong with that url, try writing a simple test to verify your routes: https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcRouteTester.MVC5/

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following posts:

[How can i make a catch all route to handle '404 page not found' queries for ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310580/how-can-i-make-a-catch-all-route-to-handle-404-page-not-found-queries-for-asp)

and

http://richarddingwall.name/2008/08/17/strategies-for-resource-based-404-errors-in-aspnet-mvc/