# Redirecting 404 error page to homepage URL with Status Code: 301

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to implement a redirection in my ASP.NET MVC web application where any page with status 404 shall redirect to the Homepage URL and at the same time it shall be a permanent redirect i.e. it shall return status code : 301.

Can someone please help ? What changes shall I do in my web.config file ?
Let me know if you require more details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a catch all route to handle '404 page not found' queries for ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310580/how-to-make-a-catch-all-route-to-handle-404-page-not-found-queries-for-asp-net)

Comment: Thats annoying...if I type in a url and you keep showing me the home page, I will think your site has a bug and most likely not visit it again.