# ASP.NET C# MVC how to redirect user to 404 page when Controller or View not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP.NET MVC C# to make my website but I have a problem that every time I go to the link on the browser the system can't find the Controller or View it won't be able to access the web. can i redirect to 404 page when i can't find info

[Video Link](https://streamable.com/37xh3n)

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310580/how-to-make-a-catch-all-route-to-handle-404-page-not-found-queries-for-asp-net

"catch all routes not handled"